# Is there a way to make flake8 check for type hints in the source

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm starting a new python project (python 3.5+) and I would like to enforce type hints in the entire codebase. Is there a way to do that with `flake8` or any other tool?

Comment: Add `mypy . --strict` to the CI (e.g. github workflows / gitlab CI)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Take a look at [mypy](http://mypy-lang.org/).

From the website:

> Mypy is an experimental optional static type checker for Python that aims to combine the benefits of dynamic (or "duck") typing and static typing. Mypy combines the expressive power and convenience of Python with a powerful type system and compile-time type checking. Mypy type checks standard Python programs; run them using any Python VM with basically no runtime overhead.

**EDIT**

Actually mypy is a type checker, so by default it only checks if there are errors related to types that are hinted or inferred. To also make it report non-hinted types, you can use additional command line switches as documented [here](http://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command_line.html#command-line).

> `--disallow-untyped-defs` reports an error whenever it encounters a function definition without type annotations.
>
> `--check-untyped-defs` is less severe than the previous option – it type checks the body of every function, regardless of whether it has type annotations. (By default the bodies of functions without annotations are not type checked.) It will assume all arguments have type Any and always infer Any as the return type.
>
> `--disallow-untyped-calls` reports an error whenever a function with type annotations calls a function defined without annotations.
>
> ...

Comment: I find `mypy` overly aggressive since it reports errors when it can't infer variable type that is being returned from an outside library with no type hinting. I only want to check if all my methods have full type hinting and so far I'm unable to do that.

Comment: Doesn't `--follow-imports silent` work in that case? http://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command_line.html#following-imports-or-not

Comment: Another option would be to add a `# type: ignore` comment to the lines where you use external (non-hinted) code. See http://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/common_issues.html#spurious-errors-and-locally-silencing-the-checker

Answer (score 9):

There is a plugin for `flake8` called [flake8-annotations](https://pypi.org/project/flake8-annotations/)

You can install it using

```
pip install flake8-annotations
```

So:

```
def test_function(x, y):
  pass
```

Will output:

```
./test.py:2:9: ANN001 Missing type annotation for function argument 'x'
./test.py:3:9: ANN001 Missing type annotation for function argument 'y'
./test.py:1:24: ANN201 Missing return type annotation for public function
```

And this is the correct version:

```
def test_function(x: int, y: int) -> None:
```

Answer (score 4):

Other mentioned [`mypy`](http://mypy.readthedocs.io/) which is used to check the type hints, but it *does not enforce them*. In order to be more strict about the type annotations, you need to enable the [following configuration settings](http://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config_file.html#per-module-flags):

> `disallow_untyped_calls` (Boolean, default False) disallows calling
>   functions without type annotations from functions with type
>   annotations.
>
> `disallow_untyped_defs` (Boolean, default False) disallows defining
>   functions without type annotations or with incomplete type
>   annotations.

Or, you can set these settings as [command-line arguments](http://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command_line.html#additional-command-line-flags) instead.

---

FYI, `PyLint` does not yet support forcing the type annotations, but there is a [feature request](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/647). And, I don't see anything related on the `flake8`/`pyflakes` front - consider [opening a feature request](http://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/internal/contributing.html#requesting-a-new-feature).

Comment: Take a look at the [flake8-annotations](https://pypi.org/project/flake8-annotations/) plugin

Answer (score 2):

[mypy](http://mypy-lang.org/) can be used to verify type hints for Python programs. The documentation can be found [here](http://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and is quite comprehensive.