# Make flake8 detect Python types errors

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, fastapi, flake8

Going through [FastAPI docs](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/python-types/#more-motivation), it looks like the following function

```
def get_name_with_age(name: str, age: int):
    name_with_age = name + " is this old: " + age
    return name_with_age
```

should trigger an error message in VSCode via a Python linter (mypy, in the example)

[image]

I'm already using flake8 but it doesn't detect such kinds of error. Is there a way to make flake8 behave like that?

Comment: your screenshot literally tells you the answer: use mypy

Comment: yes, this is a way. However, I need to stick with flake8, eventually extending its capabilities. Switching to or using also mypy is not a good option in my case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to make flake8 check for type hints in the source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43187829/is-there-a-way-to-make-flake8-check-for-type-hints-in-the-source)

Comment: Not really. I had already checked out such a question before posting here. They cite https://pypi.org/project/flake8-annotations/ but this plugin doesn't check expression consistency respect to involved datatypes. `flake8` can't do those checks. `mypy` looks like the only way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, but it looks impossible.

In the `mypy`, this function was provided by `"check_untyped_defs=true"`. We can disabled it with this configuration in the settings.json:

```
  "python.linting.mypyArgs": [
    "--follow-imports=silent",
    "--ignore-missing-imports",
    "--show-column-numbers",
    "--no-pretty",
    "check_untyped_defs=false"  //this line
  ],
```

And from the [official docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting#_flake8) of flake8, it only disabled these functions:

```
By default, Flake8 ignores E121, E123, E126, E226, E24, and E704.
```

But although you enable both of them, the flake8 still does not work.

So, it looks like the flake8 has not this feature.